# Drill-down contextual filtering

Tags: views

I've created a view called "Upcoming Events" that presents upcoming events in chronological order at the url `/upcoming-events/all`. Each event has associated tags. Currently my contextual filter is set so that replacing `all` in the url with a valid tag will present just events with that tag. Tags are set up as links with the url `/upcoming-events/[field_tags]`.

My question is two-fold. How do I set up the contextual filter so that adding more tags on the end of the url (`/upcoming-events/happy-hours/drupal/` for example) will further narrow the results presented to the user? Also, how do I set up the tag links to append the field tag to the end of the url rather than replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on **More** link under the contextual filter settings, there is an option to **allow multiple values**.

Enabling this option, you can use URLs like `/upcoming-events/happy-hours,drupal` to show events having both `happy-hours` **and** `drupal` tags.

[image]